# Triggering an Update a value after Insert and Delete operations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sequence

I have an activity from my SQL Server class and I'm missing only this trigger to complete it.

My teacher has asked in this activity to do the following trigger operation on a column sequential on telefone table.

After an insert statement, always keep the values in sequence like the first record is 0, the next should be 1 and there it goes.

And for the delete statement if someone removes a record the sequential value should be reordered.

I've got the insert statement working fine creating a sequence and adding it's next value to the column.

But no lucky with the delete statement.

Here's what I have so far for the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_sequencial 
ON Telefone
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @vSequencial_Ins INT, @vSequencial_Del INT

    SELECT @vSequencial_Ins = inserted.Sequencial FROM inserted
    SELECT @vSequencial_Del = deleted.Sequencial FROM deleted

    -- Check if it is an insert operation
    if(@vSequencial_Ins IS NOT NULL AND @vSequencial_Del IS NULL)
    begin
        update Telefone set Sequencial = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Sequencial
        from Telefone tel
        join inserted i on i.IdPessoa = tel.IdPessoa
    end
    -- Check if it is an delete operation
    else if(@vSequencial_Ins IS NULL AND @vSequencial_Del IS NOT NULL)
    begin
        alter sequence dbo.Sequencial
        restart with 0
    end
end
```

And this is the sequence code:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.Sequencial
    START WITH 0
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO CACHE
    ;
GO
```

My telefone table has the following values:

```
Sequencial smallint not null [PK]
IdPessoa int not null[PFK],
IdTipoTelefone tinyint not null [FK],
NumeroTelefone int not null,
DDD tinyint not null
```

**EDIT:** Got insert trigger working fine after changing the code from:

```
update Telefone set Sequencial = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Sequencial
```

To:

```
update Telefone set Sequencial = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Sequencial
from Telefone tel
join inserted i on i.IdPessoa = tel.IdPessoa
```

It now affects just the selected row instead of increasing all the fields.

Comment: Careful, triggers only "fire" once per DML operation, not once per row. Your trigger *assumes* that only one row will be effected, meaning it won't behave as you expect if 2 or more are effected.

Comment: Be aware that you're being taught to implement insane requirements. A `ROW_NUMBER()` or lone `ORDER BY` used during select will *always* be right, versus trying to maintain an ordering in a physical column.

Comment: Thanks for the alert! What can i do to solve this?

Comment: Either use only *set* based operations, as SQL is designed for. **OR** iterate over the rows in [`inserted` and `deleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) and perform [RBAR](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/) operations.

Comment: Will take a look, thanks!